# Placing single column database values into an array then calling them in another query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select

I'm having trouble with pulling database information from 'rownum' column and putting it into an array and then using that array information for my next query that randomly selects one line of the array and then displays it.

```
<?php

  // Connect to database
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysqli_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  // Select Rownum to get numbers and only where there is no value in seen.
  $firstquery = "SELECT rownum FROM num_image WHERE seen=''";

  // If there are results store them here
  $result = mysqli_query($firstquery) or die ("no query");

  // Put the results taken from the table into array so it displays as: array(56, 44, 78, ...) etc...
  $result_array = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $result_array[] = $row;
  }

  // Select the data I require
  $query = mysqli_query("SELECT number, association, image_file, skeleton, sound, colour, comments FROM num_image WHERE rownum='$row' LIMIT 1;");
  $test = mysqli_query("UPDATE num_image SET Seen='yes' WHERE rownum='$row';");

  // Fetch Results of Query, Ignore test.
  $arrayss = mysqli_fetch_row($query);    

  // Echo Results as a Json
  echo json_encode($arrayss);

?>
```

I'm not sure what I have done wrong? Does the array have to be echoed and then my $query line calls that instead?

Comment: Use `print_r($row)` to see what you actually got. And assign just the array entry you need. Then you'd probably want to loop over the first result list. -- Better yet would be investigating subqueries or a `LEFT JOIN` SELECT.

Comment: I don't really understand why you have three queries instead of, say, one !?!

Comment: What you want to pass as `$row` in where condition ?

Comment: @mario I'm getting for example `Array ( [0] => Array ( [rownum] => 56 ) [1] => Array ( [rownum] => 71 ))` how do I remove `[rownum] =>` and just have the number so it would look like: `Array ( [0] => 56 [1] => 71 )`

Comment: @AhmedGinani I want to pass only 1 of the arrays that have been pulled by $firstquery

Comment: @Strawberry Because I don't think 1 would be sufficient to do what I'm trying to do? As I'm creating an array and using that for my WHERE condition.

Comment: @aussiedan - Then you should try `implode(",",$result_array)` instead of $row in where condition

Comment: @AhmedGinani That's giving me.. `Notice: Array to string conversion 
Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given..`

Comment: You tried this `WHERE rownum IN (implode(",",$result_array))` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142961/discussion-between-aussiedan-and-ahmed-ginani).

Comment: @AhmedGinani thanks you put me on the right path and solved it, updating my question now to solved with updated code.

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are entirely mistaken.

Comment: Please use SQL parameters. You are wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Please don't put a "solved thanks" note at the top of your question. You can accept your own answer, this will also mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated code - Solved my problem**

Thanks for tips guys, it helped me wrap my head around it and came up with a working solution.

```
<?php

  // Connect to database
  include 'DB.php';
  $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  $dbs = mysqli_select_db($databaseName, $con);

  // Select Rownum to get numbers and only where there is no value in seen.
  $firstquery = "SELECT rownum FROM num_image WHERE seen=''";

  // If there are results store them here
  $result = mysqli_query($firstquery) or die ("no query");

  // Put the results taken from the table into array so it displays as: array(56, 44, 78, ...) etc...
  $result_array = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $result_array[] = $row;
  }
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($result_array); $i++) {
    $all_rownums[] = implode(',', $result_array[$i]);
  }

  //pick a random point in the array
  $random = mt_rand(0,count($all_rownums)-1);

  //store the random question
  $question = $all_rownums[$random];

  // Select the data I require
  $query = mysqli_query("SELECT number, association, image_file, skeleton, sound, colour, comments FROM num_image WHERE rownum='$question' LIMIT 1;");
  $test = mysqli_query("UPDATE num_image SET Seen='yes' WHERE rownum='$question';");

  // Fetch Results of Query, Ignore test.
  $arrayss = mysqli_fetch_row($query);    

  // Echo Results as a Json
  echo json_encode($arrayss);

?>
```

This part is what helped me solve it:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result_array); $i++) {
        $all_rownums[] = implode(',', $result_array[$i]);
      }
```

> *Happy Dance*

Comment: Although you may have solved the question as asked, do look into parameterizing your queries, as was stated in the initial question's comments.  The way that query is written, it's open to abuse from someone that might have malicious intents.  Last thing you want is all the tables in your database dropped because of poorly written queries.